# Login redirect django nao funciona

Tags: django, login

estou tentando fazer um redirect de usuarios baseado nas funções, exemplo: um admin apos o login ser enviado para o admin, o atendente ou funcionario comum, ser mandado pra uma home, porem o codigo colocado nao rediciona, apenas volta pra home, para todas as funções, como resolver?

VIEWS

```
    @login_required
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

        if user.is_active:    
        # Redirecting to the required login according to user status.
            if user.is_superuser or user.is_staff:
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('admin')  # or your url name
            else:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('')
```

SETTING.PY

```
    LOGIN_URL = 'login'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'
```

Answer (score 0):

Olha não sei se é somente isso, pois na minha cabeça eu iria estruturar isso diferente. 
Identifiquei que na sua linha 6 você está dando a função de autenticar o usuário. Mas na sua linha 1 você solicita que o usuário esteja autenticado. Temos um problema de deadlock aqui... Consegue corrigir isso e ver se era o único problema?

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa passar o caminho da url como parâmetro ou o nome de uma view pra ela ser redirecionada como no exemplo da documentação. Qual o name que vc definiu pra view login em urls.py?

1.Passando o nome da view

```
def my_view(request):
...
return redirect('some-view-name', foo='bar')
```

2.Passando a url propiamente

```
def my_view(request):
...
return redirect('/some/url/')


def my_view(request):
...
return redirect('https://example.com/')
```

Comment: Opa meu querido, muito obrigado, era isso mesmo, obrigado.